# MediaWiki Page Title Variable

Tags: php, mediawiki, skin

I am designing a skin for a MediaWiki(Version 1.15). I need to include the title of the page being called into the the skin. My question is, how to obtain the title pragmatically using php? I tried looking into the documentation of MediaWiki but I could not find anything for the version of MediaWiki I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to get the current page title is to obtain a [RequestContext](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RequestContext) or any IContextSource class, call `getTitle()` on it to get a [Title](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Title.php) object, and then call one of its getter methods, such as `getPrefixedText()`.

The [Skin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skin.php) class itself is the normal context source for skins, so in skin code, this would look something like:

```php
$title = $this->getTitle();
echo htmlspecialchars( $title->getPrefixedText() );
```

(In fact, the Skin class also provides another method named [`getRelevantTitle()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classSkin.html#af6170a03b6ccb56f1ed23a36a0ae9586) which you may want to use instead of `getTitle()`.  The main/only difference is that, on certain special pages like `Special:MovePage` that act on a particular wiki page, the "relevant" title will be that of the page being acted on, rather than of the special page itself.)

Note that many skins define their own shortcuts for things like the current page title.  For example, in the [Vector skin template code](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fskins%2FVector/88514bddc9cb447c3e267cd75bfbf12d843a1d71/VectorTemplate.php), printing the current page title is done by calling `$this->html( 'title' )`.  If you're basing your new skin on one of these existing skins, you may prefer to use the same shortcuts.